# Does a wizard pass through the Astral Plane when teleporting?

Tags: dnd-5e, teleportation, astral

My wizard has access to *[dimension door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door)* and *[misty step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step)*. The problem is that in my campaign, the [Astral Plane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#AstralPlane) is broken, inaccessible, and mingled with the Material Plane, therefore unable to be traveled through. Do teleportation spells transport targets through the Astral Plane?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In D&D 3.5 this *was* true, as the quote below shows. In D&D 5e nothing in the rules makes it necessary to travel through the astral plane to teleport.  Magic has changed.  (Plenty of things with the same name work differently in different editions of this game).

[Teleport in 3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#teleportation)

> A teleportation spell transports one or more creatures or objects a
>   great distance. The most powerful of these spells can cross planar
>   boundaries. Unlike summoning spells, the transportation is (unless
>   otherwise noted) one-way and not dispellable.   Teleportation is instantaneous travel through the Astral Plane.  Anything that blocks astral travel also blocks teleportation.

The D&D 5e rules do not add the Astral element to this spell:

> **Teleport**
>   This spell instantly transports you and up to eight willing creatures
>   of your choice that you can see within range, or a single object that
>   you can see within range, to a destination you select. If you target
>   an object, it must be able to fit entirely inside a 10-foot cube, and
>   it can’t be held or carried by an unwilling creature. (Basic Rules, p. 102; PHB p. 281)

If you have decided to nerf those spells, you should probably let them refund those spells, as they wouldn't have picked them if useless.

Comment: You might want to point out that your quote references D&D 3.5, not D&D 5.0. As you point out, they're different.

Comment: Sure, I thought that was implied, but I'll edit that to make it clear.

Comment: I moved your comparison of editions up top: the "bottom line up front" approach works better when any of us asks about something that we remember from another edition.  Also added the comparable rules text to show the difference.

Comment: Teleportation worked via the astral plane in older editions too, not just 3.5rd edition.

Answer (score 10):

## Characters do not travel through the Astral Plane when teleporting.

From the PHB

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired.

RAW, the only relevant locations are where the spellcaster starts and where he ends up. Based on the duration of the spell (Instantaneous), there isn't time to be in another plane than the one you are in. You are just making a door to another point you can imagine within range.

Now of course, since the means is not mentioned, you could easily homebrew that the players travel through the Astral Plane when teleporting, but that is not how the spell is written in the PHB.

Answer (score 7):

In the **Dead in Thay** adventure from **Tales from the Yawning Portal** ([written for D&D "Next"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/128515/Dreams-of-the-Red-Wizards-Dead-in-Thay-DD-Next), which was 5e before it was called "5e"), there is evidence that teleportation does involve inter-dimensional (planar) passage.

On page 110:

> ### Dimensional Barrier
>
> Magic secures the dungeon [...]
> no spell permits teleportation out of the zone in which the spell was cast.

The use of the subheading "Dimensional Barrier" combined with "no spell permits teleportation" suggests that teleportation is blocked because passing through a different dimension is made impossible.

There's no mention of the Astral Plane specifically, but I think there's a strong argument, based on this text, that the teleport spell in 5e still explicitly involves some other plane.

Comment: This is a great contribution.  The Tales from the Yawning Portal adventure, while _adapted for 5e_, consists of adventures written for other editions, and I have noted other things in it that don't make sense in 5e that 'slipped through' the updates.  You can improve this answer by adding which edition **Dead in Thay** was originally written for, and if you can compare it with the original module, whether the passage you cite is written that way in the original or not.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: Dead in Thay was originally written for "D&D Next" (5e before it was called 5e), so strictly speaking it wasn't adapted for 5e (unless you consider "Next" an interim product, and I think there are arguments both ways for and against that). I don't own [the original PDF](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/128515/Dreams-of-the-Red-Wizards-Dead-in-Thay-DD-Next) released in 2014 to compare with what got published in Yawning Portal.

Comment: There is [errata for TftYP](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/TftYP-Errata.pdf), and this subheading is not listed. I think at this point, it's only fair to take the authors and editors at their word: a dimensional barrier blocks teleportation.

Comment: I hadn't realized it was written for Next, since so many of the other works in that anthology are classics from previous editions.  Perhaps just mention that in the answer, then?